# Can we stop with the constant overuse of var on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

It is getting ridiculous:

```
var input = "This is a  test";
```

Comment: I like var. If var could be boiled down into a syrup, i would pour it over my waffles and eat them in front of you, the resulting enjoyment plainly visible on my face.

Comment: Any *particular* reason you're against `var`? Or are you just an anti-`var`ist?

Comment: It is not meant for every instance declaration, just ones where you don't know or a type doesn't exist yet. It litters code and is confusing to other developers.

Comment: How is 
    var input = "This is a test";
any more confusing than
    string input = "This is a test";
?

Comment: @Matt, try that on c# 2.0. No one is attacking `var`, it a riot. But of course it can get confusing, and can be abused.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich - perhaps you should edit the question, change it to a discussion about `var` use in SO. I agree there's an issue here, but you didn't put up any valid points.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Reading your comment, it seems you're confusing `var` with `dynamic`. You say you should use `var` when you don't know the type yet, that is not even possible. `var input = null;` does not compile: "Cannot assign 'null' to an implicitly-typed local variable".

Comment: @RuudLenders I'm pretty sure at the time of my posting the question dynamic wasn't a thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no doubt that `var` can be overused. However, it can also *aid* readability by emphasizing how a variable is used rather than what its exact type is, and by reducing duplication.

Eric Lippert wrote a [great comment](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61) about this topic when he was tech reviewing C# in Depth.

`var` has another very handy property in places where space is constrained - it's almost always shorter than the type name. This can be important in books and also on Stack Overflow where line lengths are fairly short.

More importantly, however, I don't think it's up to any one person to dictate the coding style used for answers. Go ahead and avoid using `var` in your own answers. Criticise answers where the use of `var` really, really leads to confusion... but accept that it's a personal preference.

Comment: Excellent quote from Eric Lippert!

Answer (score 18):

```
var answer = "no";
```

Comment: how about `var answer = false;` ?

Comment: Isaac Waller ♦

Comment: How about `var answer = processDiscussion()`? I *hope* that's a `IEnumerable<Conclusion>`, but it could be `"no"`, `1`...

Comment: var answer = "false"; would be better. Confirms the OPs point ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I've noticed that too. Here's an extreme example:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1327855/list

Someone edited another user's **answer** from:

```
Int32 count = Enumerable.Intersect(listA, listB).Count(word => word.Length > 3);
```

to:

```
var count = Enumerable.Intersect(listA, listB).Count(word => word.Length > 3);
```

I don't see any reason to do that - I wouldn't edit an answer to fit *my* coding standards.
As for weather `var` is good or not, and best practice: that belongs on SO, but it has its downsides. Personally, I try not expose too much of it to beginners (or it gets too confusing / magical), especially not instead of `int`s (as above) .

Comment: int32? maybe it should have been an int64, or perhaps an int128 with *blast processing*! Kidding aside, I agree that editing in var into someone else's code isn't very cool.